# How does Google encode the CSS classes and ID?

Tags: javascript, css, web, gmail, encode

Look at the name of the classes in the html block. They have been encoded to make it hard to understand.

```
<div id=":21r" class="ii gt m14b0b8af41495ba9 adP adO">
    <div id=":21o" class="a3s" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div dir="ltr">
            <div class="adL"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't think Google engineers are so jobless to encode classes like these manually. They must have used some tools for encoding the classes. Is there any service available for doing this?

Comment: I'd be more interested in finding out *why* they do it.

Comment: To provide more security. Names are hackable and understandable.

Comment: @jackkorbin question was "How" not "Why"

Comment: @VishnuKs C'mon dude read the first comment -_-

Comment: This is a self answered question. They have made it hard to encode. Exactly because they don't want you copying them, nor copying that.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible that what you are looking at was built in Google Web Toolkit. This environment has automatic Obfuscation depending on what you are looking to release into the world, and is the main environment used by Google when creating web applications.

The process is to write your files normally with your own class and id names, and when you compile the code is automatically obfuscated (or you run it through a compressor or program to do so).

In GWT you have to write in Java, but if you are looking for options for javascript or html/css then:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/utility-javascript-obfuscator
https://code.google.com/p/minify/